# How do I download a batch of pictures from URLs stored in a MySQL database

Tags: php, download

I have a database containing pictures URLs that looks like this:

```
DATABASE :
id / url
1 / http://www.pic1.jpg
2 / http://www.pic2.jpg
and so on (+1000)
```

I want to run a script in order to download all of them on my LOCAL hdd. Thus I want to store them as C:/wamp/www/currentproject/pictures/pic_id.jpg.

i was wondering what could be the most simple way to do it. I wanted to run a PHP script in order to get the URLs from MySQL and then use a PHP command to download each of them, something like this (pseudo code):

```
while( $url = $response->fetch() ) {
  "PHP download"($url, $localfolder, $name);
}
```

But I was not able to find such a function.

Also I heard about WGET, but I am not sure how to couple it with MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set_time_limit(1000);    
while( $url = $response->fetch() ) {
    $my_image = file_get_contents('http://aaafg.com/im.jpg');
    $my_file = fopen('path/myData.jpg','w+');// you must change image name
    fwrite($my_file,$my_image);
    fclose($my_file);
    }
```

i did not test code
(Note:You can convert this code to function)